# cv2.imshow image window placement is outside of viewable screen

Tags: python, windows, opencv, imshow

I am running Anaconda install of python35 with cv2 install from menpo.
I am having trouble with `cv2.imshow()` inconsistently placing the image window outside of the viewable screen when running code similar to the one below both as a standalone script and line by line in the console (cmd, spyder, ipython)...

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('Image71.jpg',0)
cv2.startWindowThread()
cv2.namedWindow('image')
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have also tried the above without `cv2.starWindowThread()` and `cv2.namedWindow()` with the same result. The window appears on my taskbar but is not in view, `cv2.waitKey(0)` responds to the keystroke, and I am not able to bring the window into view using any of the window arrangement shortcut keys for Windows 10 (e.g. alt+tab, Winkey + left, etc).
 My OS is Win10 version 1709. 
 Any help is much appreciated, thx!

Comment: What does window inquiring software like spy++ say about the window's visibility and coordinates?

Comment: I am not familiar with spy++. When pulling up 'Windows Properties' for the window opened by cv2.imshow(), under 'Styles' tab: "Window Styles: 14CB0000" and 'WS_VISIBLE' is listed. Under the 'General' tab "Rectangle: (2400, 185)-(4345, 1290), 1945x1105; Restored Rect: (2400, 185)-(4345, 1290), 1945x1105; Client Rect: (10, 39)-(1935, 1095), 1925x1056". Again I am unfamiliar with spy++. Hopefully this clarification is what you are asking about, @ivan_pozdeev.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
img = cv2.imread("test.png")
winname = "Test"
cv2.namedWindow(winname)        # Create a named window
cv2.moveWindow(winname, 40,30)  # Move it to (40,30)
cv2.imshow(winname, img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4):

wrapped answer by Kinght in a function for easy calling

```
def showInMovedWindow(winname, img, x, y):
    cv2.namedWindow(winname)        # Create a named window
    cv2.moveWindow(winname, x, y)   # Move it to (x,y)
    cv2.imshow(winname,img)

img = cv2.imread('path.png')
showInMovedWindow('named_window',img, 0, 200)
```